# Editing an HTML attribute in a Laravel Blade file

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a Laravel 9.0 project and I would like on the below HTML code of a view file

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-primary" style="width: 80%"></div>
```

to be able to populate the width percentage with a value from a variable (e.g.: {{ $sales->SalesPerc }} ).

I have tried the solution below, which is working,

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-primary" style="width: {{ $sales->SalesPerc }}%"></div>
```

but I am getting some errors inside Visual Studio Code ( property value expected, at-rule or selector expected).

Is there a better way to achieve this without using JavaScript? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have tried is the correct way to populate the width percentage with a value from a variable in Laravel. However, the errors you are seeing inside Visual Studio Code are most likely related to the fact that the syntax you are using is not recognized by the editor as valid CSS syntax.

To avoid these errors, you can move the inline CSS style to a separate CSS file or a  block inside your view file. For example, you could create a CSS class like this:

```
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
```

And then apply it to your HTML code like this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" style="width:{{ $sales->SalesPerc }}%"></div>
</div>
```

This way, the CSS syntax is separated from your HTML code, making it easier to read and maintain. Additionally, by using a CSS class, you can reuse the same styling across multiple elements if needed.

Comment: Thanks @DevangTomar for your answer but I can still see the {{ $sales->SalesPerc }} variable being added in the inline CSS at the same manner! Did you mean that I should added it accordingly in the separate CSS block instead?

Comment: That's correct! @JohnieG